# How to write code to avoid pep8 W502 and E504 issue

Tags: python, pep8

I couldn't find a good way to around pep8 E502 and W504

I have code like this

```py
if (foo(a, b) or 
    foo1(c, d) or
    foo2(e, f) ) and
    foo3(g, h):
```

If I write like this, then I get complain that I violate "**W504 line break after binary operator**".

However, if I add line break after binary operator, then I get complain that I violate "**E502 the backslash is redundant between brackets**"

If I couldn't make them into one line,  how should I write the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are "supposed" to write

```
if (foo(a, b)
    or foo1(c, d)
    or foo2(e, f)
    and foo3(g, h)):
```

with the binary operator at the start of the next line.

Even PEP-8 wavers a bit on this; it suggests pre-operator breaks for new code, but accepts post-operator breaks as long as it is consistent throughout a file.

(I prefer post-operator breaks. To me, it more strongly suggests that the expression will continue onto the next line. As such, I would just use `--ignore W504`.)

Comment: this triggers W503 "line break before binary operator"

Comment: This might depend on which tool you are using. `pycodestyle` doesn't report *either* one by default (possibly a new decision since I posted this answer), because there is no universal consensus (even in PEP-8) on which is correct.